# python negative searching

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as

```
    string = '''
        making the regex for project  
        is the basic work '''
```

The regex library has to match if it contains 'project' and not 'work'.

I wrote it like this:

```
bool(re.search('project.*(?!work)'))
```

It is returning the true as it was found. But it has to return the false.

Comment: Why not use [`if 'project' in s and 'work' not in s`](https://ideone.com/n3Er0w)? BTW, the regex is easy to fix with `'(?s)project(?!.*work)'`

Comment: But I need the regular expression only because my code has many regular expressions and there is one function which will search the given argument(re) and return true/false depending on presence.

Comment: This question needs revising. The example call to sea[r]ch is either wrong because it is a compiled re and yet is being passed a string that looks like an RE, when it should be 'sting', or it is a module level call and so needs the string to be searched to be passed as a second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing a negative looksahead after a quantified pattern with a lazy or greedy quantifier almost never yields expected results because of backtracking: once the `.*` matches 0+ chars other than line break chars it checks the lookahead pattern and since there is no `work` right after the end of the first line, the result is *true*.

To fix the regex, you need to make sure `.` matches line break chars (pass `re.DOTALL` modifier or add `(?s)` at the start) and move `.*` to the lookahead:

```
re.search(r'project(?!.*work)', s, re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sSlzNt/1).

This pattern means: find `project` and then fail the match if there is `check` substring after any 0+ chars.

Note that if you plan to use this regex as is, it might make more sense to use `if 'project' in s and 'work' not in s` to check for the same thing.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually meet the original requirement '... to match if it contains 'project' and not 'work'. For example, it returns true when s = 'work is not a project'.

Comment: @Nick The original regex was meant to only fail a match if there is `work` after `project`. Otherwise there is no sense using a regex, the non-regex solution is also supplied in my answer and that will check any string having `project` and not having `work`.